# multiple form fields with the same path inserting to db in spring

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, mariadb

I have to insert data to db in form fields that have the same path and i want to save it different id's but rather it concatenated it with ",", how could i possibly do it?

I tried to make some alias in SQL but it saves into same db field name with concatenated with ","

i expected in db when i insert that

EX.

db field name = description

input 1 value = "john";

input 2 value = "doe";

id description

1 john

2 doe

above is my expected result

but in my case when i insert it shows these

id description

1 john,doe

can someone help me to achieve that result ? THANKYOU!

Comment: Read about the `GROUP_CONCAT` function.

Comment: group_concat is like to combine data's for a specific id right ?
i expect that when i insert data it separates into different id is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Let me present a similar situation.  You have a database of people and you are concerned that each person might have multiple phone numbers.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    person_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(person_id) );

CREATE TABLE PhoneNumbers (
    person_id INT UNSIGNED,
    phone VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET ascii,
    type ENUM('unknown', 'cell', 'home', 'work'),
    PRIMARY KEY(person_id, phone) );
```

The table `PhoneNumbers` has a "many-to-1" relationship between phone numbers and persons.  (It does not care if two persons share the same number.)

```
SELECT  ...
        GROUP CONCAT(pn.phone) AS phone_numbers,
        ...
    FROM Persons AS p
    LEFT JOIN PhoneNumbers AS pn  USING(person_id)
    ...;
```

will deliver a commalist of phone numbers (eg: `123-456-7890,333-444-5555`) for each person being selected.  Because of the `LEFT`, it will deliver `NULL` in case a person has no associated phones.

To address your other question:  It is not practical to split a commalist into the components.

Comment: not being group concatenated, uhmm further details is that  I have a table field name called description and in my FORM field JSP I have two form field with the same path labelled as description and now if i insert data from my jsp to db in shows on db FOR EX. first input field value is ''John'' and second input field value is "Doe" when inserted in db it shows in the same column as "John,Doe". I want to separate the value of second form field into another ID , likewise array.